# Error importing Swagger Endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

The swagger file that I have created for my demo end point is valid according to the swagger validator. Unfortunately, when I attempt to import the API into GREG via the swagger json I'm told there is an error. The failure occurs whether I'm importing the file or accessing it via the [URL](https://gms-award.herokuapp.com/apidocs). The message is nearly useless and the stack trace is pasted below:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add resource /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/0.0.1/api-docs.json. An exception occurred while executing handler chain. Some or all of the arguments may be null. Cannot add the endpoint to registry. 
at     org.wso2.carbon.registry.resource.services.utils.AddResourceUtil.addResource(AddResourceUtil.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

What is GREG expecting that isn't part of the swagger definition I have created? Why is it throwing an error?

Comment: What is the WSO2 Greg version are you using?

Comment: could you attach the swagger file you are going to attach?

Comment: GREG 5.1.0... the swagger file is already posted in the original question. https://gms-award.herokuapp.com/apidocs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently a limitation with GReg-5.1.0.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-3195

Has a workaround, and this will be properly fixed in a later version of the product.

Comment: I added the host to the .json and that seems to have fixed it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in new G-Reg 5.2.0. You can download G-Reg 5.2.0 [from here](http://wso2.com/products/previous-products?a=aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnByb2R1Y3QtZGlzdC53c28yLmNvbSUyRnByb2R1Y3RzJTJGZ292ZXJuYW5jZS1yZWdpc3RyeSUyRjUuMi4wJTJGd3NvMmdyZWctNS4yLjAuemlw&p=Z3JlZ181LjIuMF9iaW5hcnk=).

If you want to stick to G-Reg 5.1.0, you can always backport the fix by applying [this fix](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/pull/147) as a patch.

Hope this helps.